# Plumbing Vent(s) for master Bath

Tags: plumbing, bathtub, drain-waste-vent, renovation, venting

I am currently adding new DWV plumbing for an existing master bathroom space. The space already has a WC and shower with proper drainage and venting. The new addition consists of a soaker tub between two lavs located on an exterior wall. The subfloor has been pulled up and plumbing has already been ran, but there are no vents currently.  I am trying to figure the easiest way to vent these 3 fixtures up to code. I cannot run the venting <45 degrees vertically until I am 6” of flood level rim of highest fixture. The best I’ve been able to come up with is circuit venting. From what I’ve read I would need to add a vent after the p trap of the most upstream fixture and after the most downstream fixture. I was hoping to connect the 2" circuit vent branch to the 3” vent stack located in the attic space that already penetrates the roof. The back wall where the new fixtures would be located is currently 1/2” plywood (interior plywood) which has been cut ~30" high running horizontally across the whole wall. I have 2 rough sketches that may help with visualization of everything. I was hoping to not have to drill holes in the 2x6 loadbearing studs if at all possible. I am open to different ways of venting if there is a better way requiring less work/demo. Thank you for your help.

[image: Current Master Bathroom Layout]

[image: Proposed Venting (may not need tub vent for circuit venting)]

[image: This is a reference I used for circuit venting]